# Google search engine results appeared on normal product search

Tags: javascript, cs-cart

Recently I have added the Google Custom Search engine on our website.

Website url : http://www.xeltek.com/

whenever I type keyword on the product search bar at the, the google search engine result pop-up comes up. It seems Product search bar value has been automatically assigned to google search engine search bar when displayed the results.

http://www.xeltek.com/?subcats=Y&status=A&pshort=Y&pfull=Y&pname=Y&pkeywords=Y&search_performed=Y&q=Gang+Programmer&dispatch=products.search

Please any one advice how can i prevent google search engine result pop-up when normal product search.

Currently we have used cs-cart shopping cart on our website.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Google Custom Search is picking up the &q= query string, if you change the search to this:

http://www.xeltek.com/?subcats=Y&status=A&pshort=Y&pfull=Y&pname=Y&pkeywords=Y&search_performed=Y&hello=gang+programmer&dispatch=products.search

...then the box is blank. You'd need to consult the Google Custom Search documentation to see if this can be changed. It might also be worth tagging your question with google-custom-search to get more responses.